# php soap server cannot reach localhost

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a php Soap webservice and a perl script that needs to call it.

But it returns the error

```
Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://xxxxxx:8888/index.php/backup/index' : 
failed to load external entity "http://xxxxxx:888/index.php/backup/index"
```

xxxxx is the dynamic hostname of my server.

IF i call the webservice from localhost with

```
$client=new SoapClient('http://localhost:8888/index.php/backup/index',array('trace' => 1));
```

If works fine, but if i try

```
$client=new SoapClient('http://xxxx:8888/index.php/backup/index',array('trace' => 1));
```

It gives me that error.

So the problem is that the remote script call the webservice with his hostname, and the webservice cannot resolve that.... how can I solve this?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue . Can you reach the URL with a browser?

Comment: To clarify...both calls are from my localhost. I can reach the site without problem. The problem is when the Soap server, after a remote re quest, try to access "himself" using the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It's inside the yii class CWebService.
It seems that is unable to resolve the name of the local host...it will always fail if called from an external host.

I resolved it forcing the name to the ip of the server in /etc/host, like

127.0.0.1       www.website.com